# #define DEVMETHOD(id, func) id: func found this in a header file ,what is the role of ":" here?

Tags: c

```
#define DEVMETHOD(id, func) id: func
```

I was going through a source code of ocf-crypto and found a strange macro .
What does role of ":" operator here and what it actually does ?

USes are

```
typedef struct {
int (*cryptodev_newsession)(device_t dev, u_int32_t *sidp, struct cryptoini *cri);
int (*cryptodev_freesession)(device_t dev, u_int64_t tid);
int (*cryptodev_process)(device_t dev, struct cryptop *crp, int hint);
int (*cryptodev_kprocess)(device_t dev, struct cryptkop *krp, int hint);
} device_method_t;



static device_method_t talitos_methods = {
/* crypto device methods */
DEVMETHOD(cryptodev_newsession, talitos_newsession),
DEVMETHOD(cryptodev_freesession,talitos_freesession),
DEVMETHOD(cryptodev_process,    talitos_process),
};
```

One more Macro

```
#define CRYPTODEV_NEWSESSION(dev, sid, cri) \
((*(dev)->methods.cryptodev_newsession)(dev,sid,cri))
```

The call

```
CRYPTODEV_NEWSESSION(cap->cc_dev, &lid, cri)
```

Comment: Are you sure `cryptodev_newsession` is a function name? I guess `talitos_newsession` should be a function name.

Comment: Thanks Please check the above edits @haccks

Answer (score 4):

The syntax `fieldname: value` is a GCC-specific [designated initialiser](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html). This syntax is considered obsolete. The struct after macro substitution:

```
    static device_method_t talitos_methods = {
        cryptodev_newsession:     talitos_newsession,
        cryptodev_freesession:    talitos_freesession,
        cryptodev_process:        talitos_process,
    };
```

can be rewritten with standard C99 initialisers:

```
    static device_method_t talitos_methods = {
        .cryptodev_newsession = talitos_newsession,
        .cryptodev_freesession = talitos_freesession,
        .cryptodev_process = talitos_process,
    };
```

The struct itself is an interface for a device. By means of this struct, each device can implement its own interface. This is a way to achieve a kind of polymorphism in C.

The second macro implements a call to the device functions. Of course, the function must know which device to operate on, so the macro ensures that the same `dev` is used for both finding the correct function from the interface and as argument to the function. (This could have been written as a function instead of a macro, thereby evaluating `dev` only once.)